# In double-precision floating point arithmetic, is incrementing/decrementing an integer by 0.5 always safe?

Tags: javascript, precision

In JS for example, is `n + 0.5 - 0.5` always going to equal `n`, for any integer n? If so is it because `0.5` is a power of 2 and so can be represented exactly?

Comment: Given you already know that some things cannot be represented exactly, how do you define "any integer n"?

Comment: For any integer n until it isn’t, yeah, which is `(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1) / 2`.